# cannot GET undefined

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy realizando mi portfolio y estoy teniendo un error con una animación de tipo transición. Cuando cambio de página mi transición se realiza pero luego al cargar la página que seleccione, se me pone la pantalla en blanco y me dice `cannot GET undefined`.

**`index.html`**: Como ven es un simple home con unos hyperlinks y esta linkeado el css y js.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="transitions.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

        <div class="transition transition-1 is-active"></div>

        <section>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="/"><span>HOME</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html"><span>ABOUT</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html"><span>CONTACT</span></a></li>
                <li><a href=""><span>GITHUB</span></a></li>
            </ul>


            <h1>Mateo Ghidini | Web Developer</h1>
        </section>
    

  <script src="main.js"></script>  

</body>
```

**`main.js`**:

```
window.onload=() =>{
    
    const transition_el = document.querySelector('.transition');
    const anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a'); 
    setTimeout(()=>{
        transition_el.classList.remove('is-active');
    }, 500);

    for(let i = 0; i<anchors.length; i++){
        const anchor = anchors[i];

        anchor.addEventListener('click', e =>{
            e.preventDefault();
            let target = e.target.href;

            transition_el.classList.add('is-active');

            setTimeout(()=>{
                window.location.href = target;
            },500);
        });
    }
}
```

**`transitions.css`**:

```
.transition-1{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    z-index: 101;
    background-color: var(--dark);
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: 0.5s ease-out;
}

.transition-1.is-active{
    opacity:1;
    pointer-events: all;
}


.transition-2{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:-100%;
    width:100%;
    bottom:0;
    z-index: 101;
    background-color: var(--dark);
    
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: 0.5s ease-out;
}

.transition-2.is-active{
    left:0px;
}


.transition-3{
    position:fixed;
    top:100%;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    height:100%;
    z-index: 101;
    background-color: var(--dark);
    
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: 0.5s ease-out;
}

.transition-3.is-active{
    top:0px;
}
```

Espero que puedan ayudarme, no se si el error esta en el código de js o si es un problema de linkeo de los archivos lo cual ya trate y sigue sin funcionar.

Answer (score 2):

Okeey dado que no pude ver tus hermosas animaciones :'c
Ojalá me las pudieras compartir :D

El error que tienes es el siguiente:

```
   let target = e.target.href;
```

Lo que intentas obtener es un  atributo de los enlaces no una subclase, ¿Me explico?
Si quieres obtener el valor del los enlaces. una más larga que la otra;

La primera:

```
links[0].getAttribute('href')
```

Lo que obtienes aquí es:El contenido del  href, por ejemplo: tu etiqueta home tiene el siguiente valor "/"

la segunda es lo mismo, peero es más larga y parecido a lo que intentas hacer:

```
links[0].attributes[0].nodeValue
```

Nota: Todo lo anterior lo probé con la consola, por eso no concuerda. Ocupando tu  código  quedaría así:

```
 anchor.addEventListener('click', e =>{
        e.preventDefault();
       let target = anchor.getAttribute('href');

        transition_el.classList.add('is-active');

        setTimeout(()=>{
            window.location.href = target;
        },500);
    });
```

Qués es lo pasa: Lo que pasa es que al darle click a uno  de los enlaces, éste se redirige sin problemas te pone la animación y toda la cosa. Ahora cuando  cargas tu página lo que el código busca es el valor del href y es por eso que te marca ese error.

Cuando lo probé mediante consola tu  target me marcaba undefined porque no lo tenías puesto correctamente.
Al modificarlo ya me deba el resultado que quería o querías.

Un consejo que te doy es: siempre prueba todo el código en la consola ( pon toodos los console.logs que necesites) o si quieres obtener un resultado distinto; empieza haciendolo en la consola.  Ahí  sabrás si obtendrás algún error o el resultado deseado desde un principio :D

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/target) no necesariamente devuelve el elemento al que se asignó el evento, si contiene hijos, puede devolver el que realmente recibió el clic.

Asignando evento `click` a todos los enlaces:

```
<a href="//www.google.com">Google</a> <!-- e.target será el enlace -->
<a href="/"><span>HOME</span></a> <!-- e.target será el span, no el enlace -->
```

En tu caso, el error se da porque obtienes el elemento que dispara el evento, un *span* que no tiene el atributo `href`, resultando en `cannot GET undefined`.

La opción más sencilla (y más adecuada) es usar [`event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) para obtener el elemento al que se asignó el evento:

```
<a href="//www.google.com">Google</a> <!-- e.currentTarget será el enlace -->
<a href="/"><span>HOME</span></a> <!-- e.currentTarget será también el enlace -->
```

Hay otras formas de acceder al elemento y lo dejo en un fragmento de código, junto con algunas recomendaciones:

- No uses `window.onload` para ejecutar una función al cargar la página, porque solo se puede usar una vez y podría afectar a otros scripts que usen el mismo método. Se van a sobrescribir y solo se ejecutará el que se haya declarado al final, antes de terminar la carga de la página.
  Es mejor asignar eventos con `.addEventListener()`, eligiendo [el más apropiado](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) de acuerdo a las acciones a realizar.
- En lugar de recorrer los enlaces con un ciclo `for`, simplifica con [.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) que, además, declara una variable que puedes usar dentro para acceder al elemento sin tener en cuenta el evento cuando se asigna con una función anónima (dentro del mismo contexto).

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a');
    
    anchors.forEach(anchor => {
        anchor.addEventListener('click', e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            // e.target no contiene necesariamente el enlace, puede ser un hijo
            console.log('e.target = ', e.target);
            // Puedes buscar con closest()
            console.log('Con closest() = ', e.target.closest('a'));
            // e.currentTarget devuelve el elemento al que se asignó el evento
            console.log('e.currentTarget = ', e.currentTarget);
            // O usar directamente la variable declarada para el ciclo
            console.log('Con variable: ', anchor);
            
            // Obtener href de cualquiera de las opciones que devuelven un enlace
            let target = e.currentTarget.href;
            console.log('target = ', target);
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="transition transition-1 is-active"></div>

        <section>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="/"><span>HOME</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html"><span>ABOUT</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html"><span>CONTACT</span></a></li>
                <li><a href=""><span>GITHUB</span></a></li>
            </ul>


            <h1>Mateo Ghidini | Web Developer</h1>
        </section>
    
<a href="//www.google.com">Otro enlace</a>
```